# how to Find element Locator in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor

Iam new to protractor, Please help me to find the element locator using below code in Protractor/angularJS i have tried using xpath and CSS. what locator can be used from this code

```
<button type="submit" value="autofocus" class="btn" data-ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Try this: `element(by.css('.btn'))`

Comment: thanks for time but the thing is element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Reset')); worked. ur code didnt show be error but it didnt even click the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are various methods you can use apart from xpath and css. Locators specific to Protractor -

1. Get element using `buttonText`.

   ```
   element(by.buttonText('Reset'));
   ```
2. You can also add a custom locator for your button using `addLocator` in protractor. [Here's an example of it](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator).
3. Use `cssContainingText` to get the element using both css and text properties.

   ```
   element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Reset'));
   ```
4. If at all you have a longer text in your button element(for ex, "Reset This Value"), then use `partialButtonText` to get it.

   ```
   element(by.partialButtonText('Value'));
   ```
5. You can also use a shortcut to find elements using css.

   ```
   $('.btn'); // = element(by.css('.btn'))
   ```

[More details of the locators in Protractor are here](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy).

You can use various General locators too -

1. Use `className` to get the element -

   ```
   element(by.className('btn'));
   ```
2. Use tagName to get the element if its the only button element on the page, which is a rare case -

   ```
   element(by.tagName('button'));
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for time element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Reset')); worked out thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

`element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Reset'));`

Above answer worked out.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
element(by.className("btn"));
```

or

```
$('.btn');
```

or

```
element(by.css("btn"));
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use elementor (elementor URL) for protractor to find element locator. this will help u in finding the exact locator without any issues. but little bit time consuming. but u dont need to worry on the elements found.

elementor URL in command prompt after starting the protractor.